# Is there a plugin for Pluma (RIP Gedit) to highlight matching HTML tags?

Tags: html, text-editor, syntax-highlighting, gedit

That'd be neat. I couldn't find one using google though. Anyone heard or seen something for Pluma or wanna make a plugin?

(Pluma is the text editor for Mate Desktop. Mate Desktop is a fork of Gnome 2, so Pluma is a fork of Gnome 2's Gedit).

Comment: Yes, Pluma is MATE's official text editor.  But this doesn't stop you from installing and running Gedit under MATE.  Gedit is not dead.  It is still maintained as part of GNOME -- and it works just fine under MATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That answer is no, not yet. I couldn't find one. Perhaps one day someone will create such a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good start...

[A gedit code completion framework based on a json library](https://github.com/nagaozen/gedit-plugin-codecompletion).

Comment: Hmmm. I must try! My Arch Linux is down right now though.... That plugin matches HTML tags?

Answer (score 0):

gedit 2.30.3, Edit/Preferences, first tab, Bracket matching

Comment: Bracket matching isn't the same as HTML tag matching. I'd like to click on a <div> tag, and it would also highlight the </div> tag.

Comment: Oops, my bad, then I think there is none. There isn't a more simple version that would highlight me the `def/end` pairs, or `do/end` pairs.